# Conditional if statement for Matrix dropdown option

Tags: matrix, field, conditional, fieldtypes, drop-down

Ok, so I've tidied up the code a bit and using `option.selected` instead of `option` to see if the option is selected. But, it isn't behaving how I'd expect it:

```
{% for telephone in user.profilePhone.type('details') %}
    <li>
      {% if telephone.type == 'details' %}
        {% for option in telephone.icon.options %}
            {% if option.selected == 'mobile' %}
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-mobile"></i>
            {% elseif option.selected == 'home' %}
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>
            {% else %}
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if telephone.country %}{{ telephone.country }}{% endif %}
        {{ telephone.number }}
      {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

So this is how I read it:

1. Loop through all Block Types `details`

   - As I understood from the docs, there is no need to be specific if there's only one Block Type (regardless of max blocks setting). The extra `if` conditional seems redundant?
   - I also understood that a `for loop` would act as a conditional anyway, so it would return false if no Blocks existed?
2. Loop through the `icon` dropdown options

   - Whichever one is selected, display it's corresponding icon.

But what it actually outputs is this:

[image: Wrong icon output]

So it's outputting all of the available options, not just the selected one (and not even the correct icons). I've managed (with separate if statements for just `'home'` and `'mobile'` to get this:

[image]

But it's still outputting all options declared in the if statement, instead of the desired single icon. Here are the dropdown options:

[image]

I'm new to programming, so perhaps I'm getting muddled up with things, but it seems like it should only output the icon I want, not the entire dropdown list (I realise I may need another conditional for if `'other'` or `'work'` is selected)

Perhaps the issue is you can't check in the `for loop` for **just** the selected option with an [if condition](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition). Something like:

`{% for option in telephone.icon.options if option.selected %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, you have a matrix block `telephone`, which contains a dropdown field `telephone.icon`, and you want the value of the selected dropdown option. That value is `telephone.icon.value` (which will be one of *mobile*, *home*, *work*, or *other*).

```
{% for telephone in user.profilePhone %}
  <li>
    {% if telephone.icon.value == 'mobile' %}
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-mobile"></i>
    {% elseif telephone.icon.value == 'home' %}
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>
    {% else %}
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i>
    {% endif %}

    {% if telephone.country %}{{ telephone.country }}{% endif %}
    {{ telephone.number }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, seems to work great! I didn't realise you could access this outside of the `{% for option in telephone.icon.options %}` loop. So, presumably you could use a similar method for radio buttons etc — are there any snippets of this in the docs? It's not clear from the [dropdown snippets](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/dropdown-fields) yet it's pretty simple to do. Thanks!